# rewrite the url in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a link like

```
http://for.example.com/?type=foo-bar
```

and i want it to be displayed in the address bar like this

```
http://for.example.com/foo-bar
```

so when the user types

```
http://for.example.com/foo-bar
```

it should re-direct to

```
http://for.example.com/?type=foo-bar
```

without the user knowing about the backend query string processing

plz help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^foo-bar?$  index.php?type=foo-bar [QSA,L]
```

Or if you want to use different variables (values) instead of "bar"

```
RewriteRule ^foo-([A-Za-z0-9_]+)?$  index.php?type=foo&someVar=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But you couldn't use dash (-) after "foo-", only alphanumeric and underscore.